# Why Linker does not throw, multiple function declaration error?

Tags: c, function, linker

Following are three files,

```
/* HANDLERS.H */
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

/* Functions  declarations - included in both UI.C & tiffhandler.c */
int canHandle(char *);
int drawImage(char *);
int saveFile(char *);
```

---

```
/* tiffhandler.c */
#include "HANDLERS.H"

int canHandle(char *fileName){
    return TRUE;
}

int drawImage(char *fileName){
    return TRUE;
}

int saveFile(char *fileName){
    return TRUE; 
}
```

---

```
/* UI.C */
#include "HANDLERS.H"
int main(void){
}
```

---

that are compiled as,

> >gcc HANDLERS.H tiffhandler.c UI.C

My question,

`HANDLERS.H` is included in both `UI.C` & `tiffhandler.c`. So, function declarations are included in both.

During linking phase, before `tiffhandler.o` & `UI.o` are linked, Why linker does not complain, by saying,  multiple function declarations for each function(say `canHandle`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because multiple function declarations are perfectly legal. Only multiple function definitions are disallowed.

It is okay to repeat the declaration:

```
int canHandle(char *);
int canHandle(char *);
```

But the following is incorrect since it repeats a definition:

```
int canHandle(char *fileName){
    return TRUE;
}

int canHandle(char *fileName){
    return TRUE;
}
```

The prohibition against multiple definitions of the same function is enforced by both the compiler (inside a single translation unit) and the linker (across multiple translation units).

Answer (score 1):

The linker will only fail if you have multiple function **definitions** in a compilation unit. So even the following is ok in a file:

```
void func(void);
void func(void);
void func(void);
```